# How to change Submit Order button on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, sales-quote

[image]
How can I change the "**Submit Order**" button on new order view?
I tried changing

> Magento_Sales::order/create/totals.phtml

Text get changes, but the page does not refresh on adding or deleting a product.

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @nuwaus You please explain more detail?